# How to display a 'live' count of total files uploaded?

Tags: php, javascript, counter

I am looking to display the total number of files in a database. To clarify, say I had a website where people could upload pictures of their cars, and I wanted to display a live number of how many pictures there are, what would be the best way to do this? Javascript, php? A mix? I envision a div with a number saying "Total Pictures: x" and where x would be whatever the live total is. I plan on using MySQL to store all the data on the website. Is this even recommended to have something communicate with the server this much? Is there a name for displaying a live number? Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is XHR Polling. You will need to setup a page that displays only the count of `total files`. `totalcounts.php`, and then have JavaScript get this file via ajax every set interval (1, 2 minutes?). Then change the div or html to reflect the new information. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) is to get started. Good luck! If you have any questions, feel free to come back.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate the incredibly quick response. This sounds perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking **to use the AngularJS way**, you could create a Poller service which polls every second (assuming your /counter.php returns json):

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
  var data = { response: {}};
  var poller = function() {
    $http.get('/counter.php').then(function(r) {
      data.response = r.data;
      $timeout(poller, 1000);
    });      
  };
  poller();
  return {
    data: data
  };
});
```

Then your controller:

```
app.controller('CounterCtrl', function(Poller, $scope){
    $scope.counter = Poller.data;
});
```

And finally in your view:

```
{{counter.response}}
```

You can read more about [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

---

Answer (score 0):

Set up a PHP script that queries the database and returns the total file upload count. After that, you can use JavaScript on the page to periodically call the server in a specified interval of time and fetch the count data from your PHP script. Using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) and [`GET`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get( '/counter.php', function(fileUploadCount){
      $('#counter').html( fileUploadCount );
    });
  },20000); // 20 seconds
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<p><span id='counter'>xx</span> files have been uploaded so far!</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How live do you want it to be? Just whenever someone updates the site it's going to have the new value or do you actually want it to update in near real-time?

If it's the latter you have to use Javascript against some kind of API that returns the amount of files in the database. I can't help you with that bit since you are using PHP, but it shouldn't be too hard. Just return some [JSON](http://json.org/) looking something like

```
{ fileCount: 45020 }
```

Client-side you have a few options. You have the different javascript frameworks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/) (and many more), as well as just 'plain old' javascript and frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

The keyword is really [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), even if that is just a sort of buzzword for using javascript to make websites dynamic.

I am a fan of using AngularJS because it's easy, but I'll try to give you some pointers for using jQuery first. Note that I have not used jQuery in years now.

**The jQuery way**

jQuery has a function called [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), and according to the documentation you can use that function something like this:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "http://example.com/api/fileCount.json")
.done(function(data) { console.log(data) })
.fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); })
.always(function() { console.log( "complete" ); });
```

So this means we can call an endpoint and fetch some data using jQuery.

[Here is a link](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net) to a tutorial about the basics of jQuery by the way.

jQuery makes us able to do things like this:

```
<div id="divTest1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");
</script>
```

When that is executed the div with id "divTest1" will contain the text 'Hello, world!'.

That sounds like something we could use here!

Javascript also has this really nice function called [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout), which allows us to make it call a function later.

[This](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/) describes how to use jQuery with *setTimeout()*

As you can see it also shows us *jQuery.documentReady()*, which is an event that fires when the website is finished loading, so it is a good place to put code we want executed.
The example below shows how to use jQuery to hide a div with id=div after 3 seconds.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout( "jQuery('#div').hide();",3000 ); //hide a div after 3 seconds
});
```

Combining these things you should be able to make a repeating call that fetches data from your server and then updates a div or another element with the data you have fetched.

Just create a function which uses *jQuery.getJSON()* to fetch data, and then at the bottom of that add a setTimeout call to run itself in X seconds (however often you want it to update).

In *jQuery.documentReady()* you call that function the first time the document loads.

And in the .done() bit of the getJSON() call you add the data you got from the server to your div with whatever html you want. I showed you how to use *$("#divTest1").text()*, but there is also a *.html()* which acts the same but you should use it to add html to a element.

The angular way would be to use AngularJS's [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) to do the same thing, but I wouldn't recommend learning AngularJS until you have a bit of a better grasp on Javascript.

When you do though, I highly recommend it. It's a much better approach than using jQuery.

You can read about AngularJS [here](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/why-does-angular-dot-js-rock/)

I hope this helps!